# Memory Leak adding Subview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to add a subview on ImageView control, I think, i have alloc view and dealloc view properly.This is my code.

```
for(int Count =0; Count < [list count]; Count++)
    {
        MapCallout *callout = [list objectAtIndex:Count];

        CGSize constSize = { 700.0f, 40.0f };
        NSString * sTmp = [callout.Name stringByAppendingString:@"WW"];
        CGSize textSize = [sTmp sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:25.0] constrainedToSize:constSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
        int xValue = callout.X;
        int yValue = callout.Y;
        int position = 0;

        UIImage *calloutImage;

        if(callout.Direction==0)
        {
            calloutImage=[UIImage newImageFromResource:@"arrow-0.png"];
            callout.Y=callout.Y-3; position= -3;
        }
        else if(callout.Direction==1)
        {
            calloutImage=[UIImage newImageFromResource:@"arrow-1.png"];
            callout.Y=callout.Y-3; position= -3;
        }
        else if(callout.Direction==2)
        {
            callout.Y=callout.Y + 2;
            calloutImage=[UIImage newImageFromResource:@"arrow_2.png"];
            position= +2;
        }


        CalloutButton *calloutButton = nil;

        int arraySize = [dequeueReusableCallout count] - 1; 
        if(Count > arraySize)
        {
            calloutButton = [[[CalloutButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue,
                                                                                          self.tapDetectingImageView.frame.origin.y + yValue ,
                                                                                          textSize.width,40)] autorelease];

            [calloutButton setDelegate:self];

            [dequeueReusableCallout addObject:calloutButton];
        }


        calloutButton = [dequeueReusableCallout objectAtIndex:Count];
        [calloutButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xValue,
                                           self.tapDetectingImageView.frame.origin.y + yValue ,
                                           textSize.width,40)] ;
        [calloutButton  setBackgroundImage:calloutImage andText:callout.Name andYvalue:position];
        calloutButton.tag = callout.ID;
        calloutButton.ViewMapType = [callout.calloutType intValue];
        calloutButton.isLive = callout.isLive;
        calloutButton.isAnimated = callout.isAnimated;
        [self.tapDetectingImageView addSubview:calloutButton];
    }





  //Callout Button Method


-(void) setBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)image andText:(NSString*)text andYvalue:(double)Y
{

    if(!btnCallout)
        btnCallout = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [btnCallout setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -Y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [btnCallout setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnCallout addTarget:self action:@selector(CalloutTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:btnCallout];


    if(!lblCallout)
        lblCallout = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [lblCallout setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    lblCallout.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblCallout.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:42.0];
    lblCallout.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    lblCallout.text = text;
    lblCallout.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lblCallout.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:25.0];
    [self addSubview:lblCallout];


}


    [self viewForZoomingInScrollView:self.mapScrollView];

}
```

If i call this method method multi-times, memory warning is occur and app get crash.
Here, **[self.tapDetectingImageView addSubview:calloutButton];** I if comment this statement, it is working properly. Please let me know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `[calloutButton release]` after you add it to the `dequeueReusableCallout` array since the array now has a retain on the newly allocated instance

Comment: I did as you said, but no result.Actually i called this method continuously more then 100 times for testing purpose, when it reach around 90th click, it gets memory warning.

Comment: In that case, I might look into allocating new instances of calloutButton directly when you prepare them to add them as subviews.  That way you can release them after you add them (since the view will hold a retain on the item).  I believe that now you keep adding retain counts when you're adding them from the array item.  So in that case, you wouldn't need the dequeueReusableCallout array at all.  If that doesn't do the trick, it may have something do with not removing them from their superview once you're done with them

Comment: Before calling this method, i have remove it from superview for(UIView *subView in self.tapDetectingImageView.subviews)
  {
   [subView removeFromSuperview];
  }

Comment: Try calling a release of `calloutButton` after you add it to the subview as well as after you add it to the array.  If my thinking is correct, you add a new retain each time you add it to the subview.  In order to keep the retain down, that may be what you have to do.  If not, I would set up log statements throughout the method to check retainCount.  Something like `NSLog(@"retain count %d", [calloutButton retainCount])` to see where it's adding the extra retains

Comment: Thanks,I checked it has more than 1 retain count, i released it properly as you guide. But even-though i get memory warning level 2 and crash.

Comment: It was 3 retain count, now it has only one retain count.

Comment: I'd say it's probably coming from somewhere else, and not your button.  That is way too low of a retain count to be causing a crash.  Looking at the code, I have no idea where that would be, offhand.  If I were you, I'd set up a bunch of log statements to check different values in different places to see what is going on.  That or run it through the debugger with a couple breakpoints, like at the end of the for loop, to check values during runtime.  Also, I'd check `NSLog(@"subviews %@", tapDetectingImageView.subviews)` to see if that's getting out of hand